# Unexpected result of document.getElementById.value?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

When I run the following code:

```
document.getElementById('somevar').value = '25';
alert(document.getElementById('somevar').value );
```

"`somevar`" is displayed, instead of `25`. Why is this? Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: input type of 'somevar'is hidden

Comment: Do you have any other code you are trying because this works. http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/mCLnQ/

Comment: What type of control is "somevar"? I just tested this with a textbox and it worked fine.

Comment: Works, even for a div. What kind of element is this about? Which browser?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Achilleterzo/kcp2n/ here also is an hidden input but work, as answered by Jaimec, is an execution problem i think...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is happening because when you run the code the element you're trying to access is not yet ready. Make sure you run your code after the DOM has loaded by using `onload` for plain javascript or the `ready` event if using jQuery.

Comment: Yes..that was the prob. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As show on my fiddle, if an element is defined with the right name, it show the correct result:

http://jsfiddle.net/Achilleterzo/kcp2n/

Answer (score 0):

It should work.
Here is a sample on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JBpgN/)